# Automatically next activity if in edit text is any text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have problem with edit text.I want if edit text are six characters go to next actitvity. I write this code but if write six characters don't go next activity.

this my code

```
smsCode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                if (s.toString().trim().length()== 6){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(SmsCodeActivity.this,ScanQrCodeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
    });
```

Comment: write that code in onTextChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
smsCode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if(smsCode.getText().toString().trim().length()== 6){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SmsCodeActivity.this,ScanQrCodeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
    });
```

Comment: If this helps. Make this as right answer so other get help

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your work in `onTextChanged`

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

if (smsCode.getText().toString().trim().length()== 6){

                Intent intent = new Intent(SmsCodeActivity.this,ScanQrCodeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```